# How to check IS NULL on Hibernate Custom Data Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with a Hibernate Custom Data Type (AttributeConverter) in Spring Boot 3
I have written a converter, an annotation, a validator, descriptor etc.. So far everything works.

Now I wrote a very simple SQL in a JPA repo and I am wondering that it does not work:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE ((:#{#iValue} IS NULL AND a.value IS NULL) OR a.value = :#{#iValue})")
MyEntity findByValue(@Param("iValue") MyDataType value)
```

and get the error message:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for org.example.MyDataType
```

I have now found out that it is based on the check with NULL and the value is not NULL.

That means the upper query works without the error message if `value == null`. If `value != null`, the above error message comes.

1. Question, what else do I need to enter where so that the check for != null works.
2. Is there a more elegant way than `((:#{#iValue} IS NULL AND a.value IS NULL) OR a.value = :#{#iValue})`.
   `a.value = :#{#iValue}` does not work for null values. Hibernate does not automatically convert this to `IS NULL` if the value is NULL. I have not found anything on the internet how to solve this differently.

EDIT:  It seems the bug has been brought back to life. It was once solved and has now come back to life in Hibernate 6 only in reverse.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2549

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8697

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9901

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9320

Comment: `(:#{#iValue} IS NULL AND a.value IS NULL)` -> `(:#{#iValue == null} = true AND a.value IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE ((:iValue IS NULL AND a.value IS NULL) OR a.value = :iValue)")
MyEntity findByValue(@Param("iValue") MyDataType value)
```

without `#{#...}`